# how to add new block in navigation prestashop with a module?

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I want to write a wallet module for PrestaShop
I want to put a link connected to the wallet section in the nav tag

Does it have a special hook?

Does it have a special hook or can the source code be modified through the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple hooks such as `displayTop`, `displayNav1` or `displayNav2`.

To have a more exhaustive list, I suggest you to go under the `Appearance > Positions` section in the Back-office.

You will find a list of the hooks already used and the modules.

Otherwise you can search for `{hook h='display` in your theme!